# Js auto expanding div does not work in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a auto expanding div on a website I am designing, but it does not seem t work on the page (while working fine on jsfiddle.net)

Script: http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/1057/

```
var lol;
lol = 0;

$('#question').click(function(){
    if (lol==0){
      $('#question').animate({height:'300'});
      lol = 1;
    }else{
      $('#question').animate({height:'0'});
      lol = 0;                     
    }
})
```

And here is the page I am trying to implemet it on: http://www.trulyscience.com/test/index.html (the red "questions" thing on the sie)

I really don't know what I am doing wrong, I've checked many related threads, and most of the worked but also only on Jsfiddle and not my page.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Where is the jQuery code on the page it doesn't work on? I don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the trigger method to do this, calling it after declaring the event click on the "#question":

```
function loadQuestion(){

    var lol;
    lol = 0;

    $('#question').click(function(){
        if (lol==0){
          $('#question').animate({height:'300'});
          lol = 1;
        }else{
          $('#question').animate({height:'0'});
          lol = 0;                     
        }
    });

    $('#question').trigger('click'); // Simulating click
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadQuestion();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/1058/

Comment: Additional question, can iy be tweaked to not collapse on itsself when you press the content fields? (The text, title, etc boxes)

Comment: Do not quite understand, you mean just add click on the title for example? http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/1061/

Answer (score 0):

You use two time the id question in the same html document, this may cause the issue. If you want to use the same name for elements use class instead id.

Also try to wrap your code with `$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code*/ });`

Comment: well I used 'this' first but then I got told that "this" doesn't work and I have to replace it with the id name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, on your website, `$` is not jQuery. It's a shortcut for `document.getElementById`.

I ran this code in the console after the page loaded, and the animation worked fine:

```
var lol = 0;
jQuery('#question').click(function (){
if (lol === 0){
      jQuery('#question').animate({height:'300'});
      lol = 1;
    }else{
      jQuery('#question').animate({height:'20'});
      lol = 0;                     
    }
});
```

Comment: I put it in now, and it does not work, am I doing something wrong?